# Error in binary String to Integer converter

Tags: java, string, algorithm, parsing, binary

I have binary String To Integer method implemented in my code. Problem is that I'm getting wrong last two digits of method output results, e.g.:

**SHOULD BE RESULT :** 11111111100001001000101110000100

**RESULT :** 11111111100001001000101110000011

There is always problem with last two digits of result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

code:

```
public static int binaryStringToInteger (String binaryString){
char[] digits = binaryString.toCharArray();
int binaryInteger = 0;
int count = 0;
for(int i=digits.length-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    if(digits[i]=='1') 
         {
          binaryInteger +=(int)Math.pow(2, count);
         }
    count++;
  }
 return binaryInteger;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand one thing, namely you wrote that expected result is 11111111100001001000101110000100, while your method is returning an int.

Comment: @Suspended method is returning int, and result I'm getting and expected one are printed with Integer.toBinaryString(binaryInteger);

Comment: Thank you, that clears up the fog.

Comment: @Suspended have you any idea?

Comment: You're not by chance encountering an overflow problem on your last multiplication by 2, are you?

Comment: Honestly, no mate. Your code looks ok to me. I'll try to run it on my machine once I do OS changeover.

Comment: @swingMan sorry, but I don't know

Comment: Change your `int`s to `long`, and `(long)Math.pow(2, count);`.

Comment: Or try with a 0 as first char in binary string. Is this a signed vs unsigned overflow problem?

Comment: @redge solution from DigitalNinja worked. I think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code except int type can only hold so much. Int holds 4 bytes that is 8bitsx4 = 32 bits with the first one reserved for sign, negative if 1 and positive if 0. 
Try using long int which holds 64 bits:

```
public static long binaryStringToInteger (String binaryString){
    char[] digits = binaryString.toCharArray();
    long binaryInteger = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=digits.length-1;i>=0;i--)
      {
        if(digits[i]=='1') 
             {
              binaryInteger +=(long)Math.pow(2, count);
             }
        count++;
      }
     return binaryInteger;
    }
```

Also check this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Great if a log was the desired outcome but I thought we were looking for int so a sign would be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

```
public static long binaryStringToInteger (String binaryString){
char[] digits = binaryString.toCharArray();
long binaryInteger = 0;
long count = 0;
for(int i=digits.length-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    if(digits[i]=='1') 
     {
      binaryInteger +=(long)Math.pow(2, count);
     }
count++;
}
 return binaryInteger;
}
```

And when converting `binaryInteger`:

```
Long.toBinaryString(binaryInteger);
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful

Comment: I believe it's because of the same reason ppDemo pointed out. He needs `long` to hold the large value from `Math.pow(2, count)`. Just one less bit in the binary string and his code works fine, that one additional bit takes it over. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

You got conversion issues:

`2^31 > 2^31-1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Therefore the following section from the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) describes the conversion from `double` to `int`:

> The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result [...] is the largest representable value of type int [...].

Hence the last value added is `2^31-1` and not `2^31` which causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this test result might help. 
It shows you whats going on quite explicitly.

```
binStr = 1 int = 1
binStr = 11 int = 3
binStr = 111 int = 7
binStr = 1111 int = 15
binStr = 11111 int = 31
binStr = 111111 int = 63
binStr = 1111111 int = 127
binStr = 11111111 int = 255
binStr = 111111111 int = 511
binStr = 1111111111 int = 1023
binStr = 11111111111 int = 2047
binStr = 111111111111 int = 4095
binStr = 1111111111111 int = 8191
binStr = 11111111111111 int = 16383
binStr = 111111111111111 int = 32767
binStr = 1111111111111111 int = 65535
binStr = 11111111111111111 int = 131071
binStr = 111111111111111111 int = 262143
binStr = 1111111111111111111 int = 524287
binStr = 11111111111111111111 int = 1048575
binStr = 111111111111111111111 int = 2097151
binStr = 1111111111111111111111 int = 4194303
binStr = 11111111111111111111111 int = 8388607
binStr = 111111111111111111111111 int = 16777215
binStr = 1111111111111111111111111 int = 33554431
binStr = 11111111111111111111111111 int = 67108863
binStr = 111111111111111111111111111 int = 134217727
binStr = 1111111111111111111111111111 int = 268435455
binStr = 11111111111111111111111111111 int = 536870911
binStr = 111111111111111111111111111111 int = 1073741823
binStr = 1111111111111111111111111111111 int = 2147483647
binStr = 11111111111111111111111111111111 int = -2
binStr = 111111111111111111111111111111111 int = 2147483645
binStr = 1111111111111111111111111111111111 int = -4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a problem with a signed integer value and so should treat the appropriate char (the last I think) a sign bit as follows.

```
public static int binaryStringToInteger (String binaryString){
    char[] digits = binaryString.toCharArray();
    int binaryInteger = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=digits.length-2; i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(digits[i]=='1') 
        {
             binaryInteger +=(int)Math.pow(2, count);
        }
        count++;
    }
    if(digits[digits.length-1] =='1') 
    {
        binaryInteger *= -1 ;
    }

    return binaryInteger;
}
```

Also Integer.toBinaryString () creates an unsigned binary string.